# Improve the layout in Android .. maybe TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use TableLayout with android.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="@string/client"
            android:width="150px"
            style="@style/Infos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/client"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:width="200px"
            style="@style/InfosPrincipale" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:text="@string/site"
            android:width="150px"
            style="@style/Infos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/site"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:width="200px"
            style="@style/InfosPrincipale" />
    </TableRow>

 ....
```

The result is a table with 4 columns of determined width.

I use a tablet and it's pretty in portrait mode but not in landscape because it use half of the screen, and I imagine that it would be ugly on phone version.

I have allways the same layout, 2 textview which are linked together. (they must be on the same line)

Is there a layout in Android which permits to show depending the size of the screen 2 or 4 columns ? or is there a way to set a 25% width on each column ? (it would be a good start)

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, you don't even need to set the weightSum to 1.

Set each cell layout_weight (sic!) to 25,

each cell layout_width to 0dp (doesn't work without it!) and

weightSum for the Row to 100.

Even more, you could escape weightSum setting totally, but layout would be more slow.
As for changing the table structure according to orientation, you can do it in code only.
I don't see what you want to do with your poor columns, but you could change their visibility to GONE and back to VISIBLE. And you'll see so many as remain visible. But weightSum then should not be set. Or change it together with columns visibility.

Answer (score 2):

this can be done with LinearLayout and its elements. the viewholder has a property called weightsum set that equal to 1. and the views inside will have a property called layoutwieght which you can set to .25 for 25%

Comment: I think you mean LinearLayout, not viewholder

Comment: you are correct sir. also check this out if that helps you with staying as a tablelayout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326319/is-there-any-way-to-make-table-columns-equal-to-a-fraction-of-the-total-width

Answer (score 2):

Try not to use absolute dimensions like 150px except for 0dp.

The TableLayout has two attributes that may be of interest for you: [`stretchColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3astretchColumns) and [`shrinkColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3ashrinkColumns).

Set your columns' widths to 0dp (if you want to distribute the available space equally) or WRAP_CONTENT (to ensure each column gets it's minimum required space plus it's fraction of the remainder).

Also you may want to set you TableLayout's width to FILL_PARENT.